# .htaccess and subdomain folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-subdomain/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

when I access to: `http://my-site.com/my-subdomain/` it works, the folder is locked.

but when I access to: `http://my-site.com/my-subdomain/img/101.jpg` It does not work, I can access the image.

how can I deny the access to any image or image folder?

Answer (score 0):

Those rules you have should work, make sure that your image isn't cached. Clear you cache and try again.

You can also consolidate your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-site.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^my-subdomain/ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: folder 'my-subdomain' is the folder 'img' is not available but the image is accessible and put the new image is not in cache